# Why I am getting signed out after sending invites to my facebook using server fbml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

I am working on a rails application & facing strange problem. I am using server fbml to invite my friends to my application.

```
<fb:serverfbml width="650px">
<script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:request-form method="post" action="<%= root_path%>" type="Example" invite="true" content="Check this!">
    <fb:req-choice url='<%= root_path%>' ' label='Check It Out' />  
    <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="check this" showborder="true" rows="4" cols="4" />
    </fb:request-form>
</script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

[image]

In case of inviting users to my application it is working fine but after inviting my facebook friends it asks me to login via my email id to find my eamil friends & when I click on skip button I am getting signed out? Is it related to rails post request somewhere? or some facebook api problem?
I want to redirect user to root_path after successful invites. How to prevent this?Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBML is already deprecated.  You should look into using the latest technology to accomplish this.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: Ya I know that still any help would be appreciated. Thank you.